# Error with required module, argument size must be >= 0

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, commonjs

I am developing a mobile application using Appcelerator and am including some configuration functions using commonJS.

The code that I am running is as follows:

app.js

```
var well = {};

well.config = require('config');
```

config.js

```
var configJson = JSON.parse(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'config.json'));
exports.getFeed = function(_feed){
    return configJson.feeds.sermon[_feed];
};
```

When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
Location:
[3,0] file:///android_asset/Resources/app.js
Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size must be >= 0 (file:///android_asset/Resources/app.js#3)
```

Am I doing something wrong to include the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to turn off fastdev and it will work fine, add this to yout tiapp.xml

```
<property name="ti.android.fastdev" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="ti.android.compilejs" type="bool">true</property>
```

I am using 1.7.2 and it is running fine on android

Comment: Does this need to be added in the android section of the xml, or just under the main ti:app area of the xml?